# Form data is not getting inserted in MySQL Database

Tags: php

Form data is not getting inserted in MYSQL . Form successfully posts data (I have checked with var dump). Please help me with this.
This is my action PHP.

```
<?php 
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname= "test";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);

    if($conn->connect_error){
    die("connection failed:" .$conn->connect_error);
    }
    else{
        echo "Connected successfully";
    }
    $selected = mysqli_select_db($conn,$dbname);



        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
        $address = $_POST['address'];
        //$gender = $_POST['male'];
        //$gender = $_POST['female'];

    $sql =  "INSERT INTO test1 (first_name,last_name,email,mob,home_address) VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$email','$mobile','$address')";

    var_dump($sql);
    ?>
```

Comment: All you did was create a string, you didn't execute a query.  You should never put user input (POST/GET) directly into a query anyways, research prepared statements and sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the last part which executes the query to save the data:

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your support